# Кластеризация в React yandex map 3.0

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-jsapi

В API 3.0 нет механизма кластеризации.
Что в этом случае делать? Правильно понимаю что кластеризацию придется писать самому или есть еще варианты?
в React проекте

Answer (score 0):

В версии 3.0 API кластеризатор реализован в отдельном [пакете](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/ref/packages/index.html) - [@yandex/ymaps3-clusterer@0.0.1](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/ref/packages/clusterer/index.html). Подключите как в [примерах](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/examples/index.html) с метками или хинтом и используйте.